# regular expression in java to check that a string is part of another string (NO SUBSTRING)

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I wonder if there is any regular expression that could allow me to check that:

if I have these strings:

- complete
- come
- emoc

I need to check that all the chars of "come"  are contained in complete BUT if i have "emoc" and try to match it with "complete" the match should return false.

As you can see this is not a "contains" case.. I need to check that all the chars of one string from left to right are contained in the larger string, but if i try to match the same characters in a different order it should not match (even if the larger string contains all the letters).

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, so you want `c` followed by any number of characters followed by `o` followed by ...

Comment: Why not use a hash instead?  Regex seems inappropriate here, and I imagine that the expression written would be hideous.

Comment: A while loop could easily solve this, a regular expression will be much harder. If the smaller word is known beforehand though, the regular expression is easy (take the word and apply '/./&\.\*/g' to it)<. If on the other hand it isn't, and you need to have one regex that will do the job for every possible input, I don't think that's possible. I hope I'm wrong though and would definitely like to see a regex to do this!

Comment: `"complete".matches(".*c.*o.*m.*e.*");` ... `"complete".matches(".*e.*m.*o.*c.*");`

Comment: i have many ways to do it but im feeling a little lazy today so i was expecting that maybe some magic regex could save my day LOL.
the regexp i was looking for should work for any input, not just for my example.. and i know which string is larger than the other before doing the match.

Comment: You should ***really*** use regex only when it's appropriate.  "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Makoto: A hash function?

Comment: It's easy, pick each character an put an ".*" before it (and another at the end of the string). You will have build your RegEx... not the best solution (for the best solution I will recommend Stack Exchange), but solves your problem. I think, haha.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth:  I was thinking of some kind of hash operation, but then you run into the special case of `emoc` not being contained in `complete`.  Perhaps a LinkedHashSet would be appropriate.

Comment: Dalton.. i already came up with (.*) but it does not work as i expect, using my example it matches  "come" and "emoc" with complete and it should only match "come".

i also did a set where i put every char of the word complete and then tried to insert in the set the chars of the smallers string counting that the collisions are equal to the size of my smaller string and i get the same issue that using (.*).

Comment: You sure? I have tried it in rubular and it works. Did you try exactly the string that I posted above (".*e.*m.*o.*c.*")?

Comment: Dalton , mmmm i gonna try that.. i will convert the string to a charArray and then use (.*) in every char and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct regex, but given the search string it is easy enough to build one:

```
    String main = "complete";
    String search = "come";

    char[] split = search.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder(".*");

    for (int i =0; i < split.length; i++) {
        regex.append(split[i]).append(".*");
    }

    System.out.println(main.matches(regex.toString()));
```

In this example, the final line prints true. If you change the value of search to "emoc" it returns false.